# jqPlot DateAxisRenderer hanging browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqplot

I am using a jqPlot line graph with the DateAxisRender on the XAxis and am seeing my browser hang. No crash, just hanging there.

The code for my chart is:

```
var lineChart = $.jqplot('viewsAppsTime', [data.VIEWS], {
  seriesColors:["#3bafe4","#00a44d"],
  grid:{
    shadow:false,
    drawBorder:false,
    drawGridlines:false,
    background:"#fff"
  },
  gridPadding:{bottom:20},
  seriesDefaults:{
    markerOptions:{
      style:"circle",
      lineWidth:5,
      size:12
    }
  },
  axesDefaults:{
    min:0,
    showTickMarks:false,
    tickOptions:{
      showLabel:true,
      showMark:false,
      showGridline:false
    }
  },
  highlighter:{
    show:true,
    tooltipAxes:"y"
  },
  title:"Visits and Applications",
  height:"340px",
  axes:{
    xaxis:{
      label:"Days Active",
      renderer: $.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer,
      tickInterval:7,
      tickOptions:{}
    }
  },
  series:[
    {
      label:"Visits",
      neighborThreshold:-1
    },{
      label:"Applications",
      neighborTheshold:-1
    }
  ],
  legend:{
    show:true,
    location:"ne",
    yOffset:0
  }
});
```

the data.VIEWS variable will look like this (copy of actual value):

```
[["2012-12-13",25],["2012-12-14",31],["2012-12-15",38],["2012-12-16",23],["2012-12-17",40],["2012-12-18",23],["2012-12-19",11],["2012-12-20",7],["2012-12-21",7],["2012-12-23",4],["2012-12-24",3],["2012-12-25",9],["2012-12-26",12],["2012-12-27",8],["2012-12-28",7],["2012-12-29",1],["2012-12-30",4],["2012-12-31",4],["2013-01-01",6],["2013-01-02",24],["2013-01-03",11],["2013-01-04",10],["2013-01-05",6],["2013-01-06",10],["2013-01-07",6],["2013-01-08",16],["2013-01-09",14],["2013-01-10",5],["2013-01-11",7],["2013-01-12",6],["2013-01-13",2]]
```

I have read through [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8588510/why-does-jqplots-dateaxisrenderer-crash-when-showing-a-single-data-point) and copied the file linked from the answer, but I still see my browser hang.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the cause of my issue was that I was using the wrong syntax for tickInterval and that I had to specify a min and max value. I modified my code as the following:

```
  axes:{
    xaxis:{
      label:"Days Active",
      renderer: $.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer,
      tickInterval:"7 days",
      min: data.VIEWS[0][0],
      max: data.VIEWS[data.VIEWS.length-1][0]
      tickOptions:{}
    }
  },
```